# Not able to fail the bamboo build

Tags: bash, shell, bamboo

We have written shell script to check the number of dispatchers in the target group and if there are 2 dispatcher instances script will remove one dispatcher instance else it will not remove if there is only one dispatcher instance . We are calling this through the bamboo job .
Script works fine, it does not remove a dispatcher if only one exists, but the bamboo does not fail the build .

Comment: I don't know bamboo, but I would assume it checks the return code of the script you ask it to execute, so I'm guessing you are missing an exit with a non-zero return code to run when your script decides it has nothing to do

Comment: Hi Aaron, We are using exit 2  return code but still no luck .

Comment: If bamboo lets you see the output of commands you might want to have it execute `bash -x your_script.sh` instead of your script. This will have bash produce debug output on stderr while executing your script (it will display the expanded commands before running them). It's frustrating to read when you're not familiar with it, but it might help you pinpoint what behaves differently when called from bamboo

Comment: Just verified for you that an exit code of 2 fails the bamboo build. You must have a bug in the script. Just paste your setup and code instead of making us guess.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed . There was no error in the script rather we had "sleep 30" in the bamboo script which we removed and post that the build started failing and its working fine as per the requirement.